# Looping through a collection of text boxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that has three conceptual groups of textboxes.  I'm trying to create a collection for each group and then when the user clicks on a button to call a sub/function associated with one of those groups, I want to be able to call a function that loops through the collection of textboxes associated with that group and check if they are empty, contain invalid characters, etc.

I've made the following declarations at the module level.

```
Dim typSectFields, laneFields, matFields As Collection
```

Then when the user form initializes I add the text boxes to the collections:

```
Set typSectFields = New Collection

    With frmAddTypSect

        typSectFields.Add txtTypSectName
        typSectFields.Add txtStartSta
        typSectFields.Add txtEndSta
    End With
```

And then when the user clicks the button that uses the input from the "typSectFields" collection:

```
Dim tb As Control, res As VbMsgBoxResult

For Each tb In typSectFields
        If tb.Text = vbNullString And t.Tag <> vbNullString Then

            res = MsgBox("You've not completed the " + tb.Tag + " field. Would you like to complete it now?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

            If res = vbYes Then Exit Sub

        End If
Next
```

I get an "Object Required" error when execution hits the For loop.
VBE shows that tb = nothing and typSectFields = Empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the code is running when you initialize the form (the `Set typSectFields = New Collection` code)?  The first thing I would do is throw a `MsgBox` in there just to be sure.

Comment: It also looks like you have a typo in there `t.Tag <> vbNullString` should be `tb.Tag <> vbNullString`.  Make sure you have `Option Explicit` set in your code module.

Comment: Yes it is running. I added a msgbox right below the `set typSectFields = New Collection` line and it displays. Also, the "locals" window in VBE shows the three textboxes being added to the typSectFields collection, but it seems like the collection is emptied when the initialize sub is exited.

Comment: I think I figured out a better way to do it. I put the controls in a frame control and then just loop through the `Frame.controls` collection. The other thin I found while trying to debug my original approach was I had the `Dim typSectFields As Collection` statement in the main code module of my project, not in the declarations for the userform. Would that be a problem?

Comment: adding frames to the form is absolutely the right way to do this, it naturally groups the controls in the frame for you.  Placing the DIM at module level, while unnecessary makes no difference.  The real problem is  that with the DIM statement for multiple tags leaving off the AS clause implies Variant type, so `DIM Tag1, Tag2 AS SomeType` is the same as `DIM Tag1 as Variant, Tag2 AS SomeType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all of your code (specifically the module-level declarations) are in the code behind the form module.  The following runs without error for me:

```
Dim typSectFields As Collection, laneFields As Collection, matFields As Collection

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim tb As Control, res As VbMsgBoxResult

    For Each tb In typSectFields
        If tb.Text = vbNullString And tb.Tag <> vbNullString Then
            res = MsgBox("You've not completed the " + tb.Tag + " field. Would you like to complete it now?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

            If res = vbYes Then Exit Sub

        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set typSectFields = New Collection

    With frmAddTypSect
        typSectFields.Add txtTypSectName
        typSectFields.Add txtStartSta
        typSectFields.Add txtEndSta
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: the difference here is `Dim typSectFields, laneFields, matFields As Collection` vs `Dim typSectFields As Collection, laneFields As Collection, matFields As Collection`  without the individual `As Collection`'s the first two variables are declared a variants, not collections